# Virtual environment installing packages globally

Tags: pip, python-venv

I have been working on a Django project, which I created and have been running in a virtual environment. I recently made the project folder a GIT repository and pushed the project up to Github.

The next time I went to run the development server I got an error message saying that Django wasn't installed.

Whilst in the virtual environment I used pip to install Django in my project folder however it is being installed globally and I can run the server outside the virtual environment.

I have uninstalled Django and tried again to install it in the virtual environment, however it is still installing globally.

```
    (venv) C:\Users\tomge\django_projects\djangodelights>pip uninstall Django
    Found existing installation: Django 4.1.7
    Uninstalling Django-4.1.7:
      Would remove:
        c:\users\tomge\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages\django-4.1.7.dist-info\*
        c:\users\tomge\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages\django\*
        c:\users\tomge\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\scripts\django-admin.exe
    Proceed (Y/n)? y
      Successfully uninstalled Django-4.1.7

    (venv) C:\Users\tomge\django_projects\djangodelights>py -m pip install django
    Collecting django
      Using cached Django-4.1.7-py3-none-any.whl (8.1 MB)
    Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse>=0.2.2 in       c:\users\tomge\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from django) (0.4.3)
    Requirement already satisfied: tzdata in     c:\users\tomge\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from django) (2023.3)
    Requirement already satisfied: asgiref<4,>=3.5.2 in     c:\users\tomge\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from django) (3.6.0)
    Installing collected packages: django
    Successfully installed django-4.1.7
    WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.4; however, version 23.0.1 is available.
    You should consider upgrading via the     'C:\Users\tomge\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Any help or advice much appreciated.

Comment: I have just set up a new virtual environment in another folder, and Django only installs inside the virtual environment, not globally. Has creating a GIT repository changed something?

Answer (score 2):

Exit Virtualenv: `deactivate`
Uninstall Global Django: `pip uninstall django`
Activate Virtualenv: `workon venv` (or whatever the non-wrapper command is)
Install Django in env: `pip install django`

Then you should be golden.

---

#### Edit

I'm presuming you accidentally installed it outside of the env and just didn't realize. I've done this many times myself, so I assume it's a common error

Comment: So this isn't working. I definitely have my virtual environment activated, but Django is still installed globally. I will add my cmd process as an answer to the question to show the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So here is my process in the cmd terminal.

I check for Django outside the virtual environment:

```
    C:\Users\tomge>django-admin --version
    'django-admin' is not recognized as an internal or external 
    command,
    operable program or batch file.
```

No Django.

I activate the virtual environment:

```
    C:\Users\tomge>cd django_projects/djangodelights

    C:\Users\tomge\django_projects\djangodelights>venv\Scripts\activate

    (venv) C:\Users\tomge\django_projects\djangodelights>
```

Then install Django:

```
    (venv) C:\Users\tomge\django_projects\djangodelights>py -m pip 
    install 
    django
    Collecting django
      Using cached Django-4.1.7-py3-none-any.whl (8.1 MB)
    Requirement already satisfied: asgiref<4,>=3.5.2 in 
    c:\users\tomge\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site- 
    packages 
    (from django) (3.6.0)
    Requirement already satisfied: tzdata in 
    c:\users\tomge\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site- 
    packages 
    (from django) (2023.3)
    Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse>=0.2.2 in 
    c:\users\tomge\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site- 
    packages 
    (from django) (0.4.3)
    Installing collected packages: django
    Successfully installed django-4.1.7
```

Django has installed globally, seemingly from cached data.

If I now deactivate the virtual environment and check for django:

```
    (venv) C:\Users\tomge\django_projects\djangodelights>venv\Scripts\deactivate
    C:\Users\tomge\django_projects\djangodelights>django-admin -- 
    version
    4.1.7
```

Django is installed globally outside the virtual environment.

Comment: Why do my code blocks never work???

Comment: You need to use ***backticks*** (not single quotes) for code blocks `text ```code``` text`.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested, I realised that I has changed the name of the root folder for the virtual environment so the correct path didn't exist anymore!!!

The moral of the story being, don't go changing the names of your folders!!!